# OS system calls in x86

Tags: operating-system, x86

While working on a educational simplistic RISC processor I was wondering about how system calls work when implementing my software interrupt function. For example, hypothetically lets say our program calls sys_end which ends the current process. Now I know this would go to a vector table and then to the code to end the current process.

My question is the code that ends the process ran in supervisor mode or user mode? No where I seem to look specifies this. I'm assuming if its in normal user mode that could pose a very significant problem as a user mode process could do say do something evil like:

for (i=0; i++; i<10000){
    int sys_fork   //creates child process
}

which could be very bad I thought the OS would have some say on how many times a process could repeat itself and not to mention what other harmful things a process could do by changing the code in the system call itself.

Answer (score 0):

system calls run in supervisor mode for the duration of the system call.  The supervisor mode is necessary for accessing hardware (the screen, the keyboard), and for keeping user processes isolated from each other.

There are (or can be configured) limits on the amount of cpu, number of processes, etc. a user process may use or request, which can offer some protection against the kind of runaway program you describe.

But the default linux configuration allows 10k processes to be created in a tight loop; I've done it myself (both intentionally and accidentally)